# WARN Could not register counter in HealthMonitor warnings in logs

Tags: health-monitor, performance, logging

I'm seeing a ton of these messages in my logs all the time.  How can I clear them up?

> Heartbeat 13:07:35 WARN  Could not register counter in HealthMonitor. Category: .NET CLR Memory, Name: # Bytes in all Heaps, Instance: , InstanceType: CLR
>           Message: Category does not exist.
>   Heartbeat 13:07:35 WARN  Could not register counter in HealthMonitor. Category: .NET CLR Memory, Name: % Time in GC, Instance: , InstanceType: CLR
>           Message: Category does not exist.
>   Heartbeat 13:07:35 WARN  Could not register counter in HealthMonitor. Category: .NET CLR Memory, Name: Large Object Heap size, Instance: , InstanceType: CLR
>           Message: Category does not exist.
>   Heartbeat 13:07:35 WARN  Could not register counter in HealthMonitor. Category: .NET CLR Loading, Name: Bytes in Loader Heap, Instance: , InstanceType: CLR
>           Message: Category does not exist.
>   Heartbeat 13:07:35 WARN  Could not register counter in HealthMonitor. Category: .NET CLR Loading, Name: Current Assemblies, Instance: , InstanceType: CLR
>           Message: Category does not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this URL speaks to your issue: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/404548

Among the other suggestions there, try to reload the perf counters:

1. Start an administrator command prompt.
2. Run unlodctr .NETFramework.
3. Run lodctr %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\CORPerfMonSymbols.ini 
   where  is the directory of the .NET Framework version which contains the CORPerfMonSymbols.ini file. It should be either v4.0.xxx or v2.0.xxx if 4.0 is not installed.
4. Restart IIS.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very good article on https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/531 which deals with the same issue. I actually followed it up last year and it solved the issue that you are having as well.

Comment: Best if one could elaborate a bit on the content of said article. The link might die out, making the link-only answer near value-less.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting: Counters.Enabled to false with a patch file and this will stop Sitecore logging out most of these counters.

You should read up on what these are for though before you do this: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/404548